# Boolean expression to determine if 8-bit input is within range

Tags: boolean-expression, twos-complement, digital-logic

Given the following in 8-bit 2s complement numbers:

```
11000011 = -61 (decimal)
00011111 = +31 (decimal)
```

I am required to obtain a **boolean expression** of a logic circuit whose output `out` goes high when its 8-bit input `in` (also in 2s complement representation) is in the following range:

```
-61 < in < 31
```

---

Number line for 8 bit numbers (2s complement):

`10000000` (most negative) ..... `11000011` (-61) ..... `00000000` ..... `00011111` (31) ..... `01111111` (most positive)

Is there any way of solving this problem besides brute-forcing and comparing bit-by-bit?

**Edit**: The following statement is not allowed

```
out = ((in < 11000011 && in > 10000000) || (in > 00011111 && in < 01111111)) ? 1'b0 : 1'b1;
```

Comment: Are you allow to use comparison `<` and `>`? Are you allow to use operator `?`? That is a if-then-else... maybe they are asking you to use only logic ports, like `AND`, `XOR`, `NOT`, etc...

Comment: Your answer seems correct. What about `out = (in >= 11000011 && in <= 00011111) ? 1'b1 : 1'b0;` ? assuming you can use `>=` and `<=` operators.

Comment: can you access each bit of the input individually like `in[7]` for bit 7 of the input, `in[6]` for bit 6 of the input, etc? If so, you could use `(~in[7] & ~in[6] & ~in[5]) | ((in[7] & in[6] & in[1] & in[0])`

Comment: @GabrielOshiro I have clarified it with the assignment setter and apparently, I'm not allowed to access the entire data stream. I only have access to the individual bits (something like your comment with in[7]-in[1]) so I went ahead and listed all the numbers out to find a pattern manually. Not pretty though. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if there is a faster way to do this. But what I did was to list the numbers out in 2s complement format before trying to find a pattern. The following chunks of numbers are sorted in numerical order (from `00000000` to `11111111` so that the pattern can be more clearly seen).

Let the MSB be `A` and LSB be `H`. The equation is: `A B C  + A B D  + A B E  + A B F  + A' B' C' D'  + A' B' C' E'  + A' B' C' F'  + A' B' C' G'  + A' B' C' H'`

`A' B' C' D'` (easiest to observe):

00000000 (<- min)
00000001
00000010
00000011
00000100
00000101
00000110
00000111
00001000
00001001
00001010
00001011
00001100
00001101
00001110
00001111

`A' B' C' E'  + A' B' C' F'  + A' B' C' G'  + A' B' C' H'`:

00010000
00010001
00010010
00010011
00010100
00010101
00010110
00010111
00011000
00011001
00011010
00011011
00011100
00011101
00011110

`A B D  + A B E  + A B F`:

11000100
11000101
11000110
11000111
11001000
11001001
11001010
11001011
11001100
11001101
11001110
11001111
11010000
11010001
11010010
11010011
11010100
11010101
11010110
11010111
11011000
11011001
11011010
11011011
11011100
11011101
11011110
11011111

`A B C` (easiest to observe):

11100000
11100001
11100010
11100011
11100100
11100101
11100110
11100111
11101000
11101001
11101010
11101011
11101100
11101101
11101110
11101111
11110000
11110001
11110010
11110011
11110100
11110101
11110110
11110111
11111000
11111001
11111010
11111011
11111100
11111101
11111110
11111111 (<-max)

Comment: cool im happy you found a solution. you can accept your own answer as the correct one